# How get model props with field is a string parameter?

Tags: laravel

How can in Laravel 9.1 app with model

a) to check if field exists
b) read field value
c) write field value,
d) get type of this field

where field is a string parameter ?
I know how

```
$model->getAttributes()
```

works and it is helpfull with a) and b)

how make c) and d)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found construction

```
  $model->{$field_name} = $value
```

usefull in my case